# Identifying an unknown transformer

Tags: transformer

I was given an unknown transformer that I need help with. It has three taps on one side and 5 taps on the other.

I was told that it was a 120 volt input transformer but when 120 volts is applied it trips the breaker in my building. I need help figuring out the input and output voltages.

I am new to all of this so please be patient.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Surely you had a low-current rating fuse in the 120 V line that you used to test the transformer?!

Comment: Where did you apply the 120 volts?

Comment: I applied 120 volts to the two outer taps on the transformer. The center on is turned up. On the three tap side two taps are flat and one is turned up it that matters

Comment: @chrisky1 Can you give us any photos of the transformer? Especially any markings on it. It's possible that the three terminal side is the secondary, not the primary. And please do be a little more careful with any further tests you run at 120 volts!

Comment: @chrisky1 I would also recommend, rather than hooking it up to mains again, measuring the resistances between each pair of terminals with a multimeter; that will help us figure out how it's connected internally. Incidentally, please use the @ feature on this site to notify people when you reply to them; I only saw this one because I'm in the habit of checking because many new people don't realize that we don't get notified if there's no @.

Comment: If you are certain that it is a 120VAC step-down transformer, measure the resistances of the coils. The highest resistance is most likely the primary. And a picture will help.

Comment: I uploaded a transformer pic to the original question.

Comment: @hearth: I loaded a photo of the transformer to the original post.

Comment: @chrisky1 Is there any difference between the three pictures? And is there any writing anywhere on the transformer? Please also take measurements of the resistances between every pair of contacts.

Comment: @Hearth: No differences in the pics. No writing anywhere. The resistances are as follows: Looking at the three tag side left tab being 1, 1-2 is .3, 1-3 is .1 ,2-3 is .2.  On the 5 tab side, 1 being the tab on the left side, 1-2 is .5, 1-3 is 1.2, 1-4 is .9, and 1-5 is 1.1

Comment: "*No differences in the pics.*" Um, why three copies of the same picture then? Welcome to EE.SE!

Comment: @Transistor: sorry for the three pics.

Comment: I would find some impedance to put in series with the windings and measure current with 120 V applied through an impedance that will limit the current to a safe level. Measure the resulting voltages and currents. Three pictures taken from different angles might help.

Answer (score 1):

Your transformer most likley is from a automotive battery charger. I've seen lots like it. Check the windings with an ohmmeter, the windings with the highest resistance should be the primary.